# JavaFX ChoiceBox EventHandling

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to detect `ChoiceBox` item selection. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522680/javafx-choicebox-events) and I know that it is possible to do, this way:

```
choiceBoxObject.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(myChangeListenerObject)
```

also I saw this sentence in Documentation for `ChoiceBox` class which confirms code above:

> ChoiceBox item selection is handled by SelectionModel As with ListView
>   and ComboBox

Another solution came to my mind and I was wondering is there anything wrong with it? why nobody mentioned this way? What is the difference between these two approaches?

```
choiceBoxObject.valueProperty().addListener(myChangeListenerObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using the `valueProperty`, and in fact for simply reacting to changes in the selected value, it's probably the preferred solution.

The documentation is just indicating that there is a complete `SelectionModel` underlying the selection of items. This has a far richer API than simply knowing what is selected: there are `selectNext()`, `selectFirst()` methods, etc etc. So if you needed to programmatically change the selection there is a rich API available. As also pointed out in the documentation, you can even replace the selection model with a different implementation, though use cases for this are likely to be (very) rare.