# How to set up a multilevel dropdown box form that is dynamically populated?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, javafx

This is my first StackOverflow question. I'm at my internship and I'm hitting a bit of a road block.

I want to implement something similar to dropdown boxes in forms that ask you for the country and state, and after selecting the country, the state menu automatically gets populated with states in said country.

I have data, of buildings, floors in those buildings, and spaces in those floors. I want to set up a multilayer dropdown box so that someone using the JavaFX form that I'm developing can just select a building from the first menu, which would then allow him to choose the floor from that building in the second dropdown box, and that would allow him to choose the exact office or space inside of that building on that floor.

I just want the second and third dropdown boxes to be properly populated based on the first and second choices.

My initial thought was to have multiple layers of tables, where the entries in the building table have a relationship to a subtable. I don't know if this is even possible. I would like some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I am voting to close this as too broad. StackOverflow is meant for specific programming questions and not so much for getting ideas on how to implement entire features. However, what you'll want to do research on is how to use a `ChangeListener` on your first `ComboBox`. When that selection changes, you can then populate the following `ComboBox`es. There are several answers on SO that can lead you in the right direction.

Comment: After researching that method, if you still run into a problem, go ahead and read the [ask] article and post a question, including a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick example in JavaFX to get you started to have them dynamically change set values for the second box in the action of the first one and so on for however many comboboxes you need

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ComboBox comboBox2 = new ComboBox();

        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().addAll("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3");
        comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
            comboBox2.getItems().clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                comboBox2.getItems().add("State "+i+" "+comboBox.getValue().toString());
            }
        });


        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, comboBox2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply have three **ChoiceBox**. The first may be statically populated, while the second and third would be initially hidden (not visible).

[At the selection event of the first one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522680/javafx-choicebox-events) you populate the second one by getting the selected element in the first one and you set it visible. Same for the third one, at the selection event of the second one.

Hint: Set an ObservableList as the items of the second and third ChoiceBox, so you just need to change the elements in the list when you get a new selection.

Last hint: remember to hide the third box again when the first ChoiceBox changes selection!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need to use SQL but if you want to read the data in from a SQL table that could be an option. If you want to hardcode in the options and use if statement logic to make the following dropdowns appear after the previous dropdown one is selected that is one possible solution.

I did something similar for a project. Here are the steps I took to create a dropdown menu:
First, create a observable list:

```
import javafx.collections.*;
#i should say wildcard imports are not optimal and you should find out what specific import you need but I am not sure so I used the wildcard.
import java.util.ArrayList;
#I am not sure what imports you have already, but you made need more
ObservableList varName = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   ComboBox<String> varName2 = new ComboBox<>(varName);
```

You should do this at the class level to avoid any scope issues. The second step is to add data to the dropdown menu. You do this with the .add() method

```
varName.add("option 1");
varName.add("option 2");
```

This adds options to the dropdown. Just as a reminder you also have to add the dropdown to the pane.